# Executing Swiftui Webview to obtain results in a sequence of asyc func calls

Tags: swiftui

I have a webview, which runs a javascript to do some calculation and return some results. The webview takes some bindings.The problem I am facing is I need to run a two async functions first, update varA, varB; then I need the result which is now been returned in the completion closure to execute the last async function. These sequence of calls has to be repeated a number of times. However, this does not work because I am dealing with a view which takes bindings. How do I fix go about this?

```
struct MyWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var varA: String
    @Binding var varB: String
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool
    var completion: (String) -> Void

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString), isLoading {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            uiView.load(request)
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: MyWebView

        init(_ parent: MyWebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        // Implement WKNavigationDelegate methods as needed

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            //
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") { result, error in 
                varA = // update 
                varB = // update
                completion(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@State result: String = ""

@ViewBuilder
func myWebView() -> some View {
MyWebView(varA: $varA, varB: $varB){ returnedResult in
    result = result
}
}
```

In the view, there is a button that is supposed to:

```
Button("Click") {
for _ 0...<3 {
Task {
  varA = await asyncFunc1()
  varB = await asyncFunc2()

  // changing the state vars triggers the webview to execute

await asyncFunc3(varA, varB, result) // the problem is result is an empty string
}
}
  
}
```

Comment: Your code does not update `varA` or `varB` at all, nor is it clear what the "last async function".

Comment: @Sweeper it is a snippet to illustrate my problem, but these vars get updated in func webView. I have added a bit more snippets